Get Azure keyvault id from two types of Terraform variable inputs
I have two types of variables in terrafrom.
First two are object() type
 variable "var1" {
  type = object({
   host_name                       = string
   key_vault_id                    = optional(string)
  })
 default = {
    host_name     = "api.example.com"
   key_vault_id  = "https://keyvault1.vault.azure.net/secrets/example-cert1"

  }
}

 variable "var2" {
   type = object({
    host_name                       = string
    key_vault_id                    = optional(string)
   })
   default = {
   host_name     = "portal.example.com"
   key_vault_id  = "https://keyvault2.vault.azure.net/secrets/example-cert2"
 }
}

and, second one is map(object())
 variable "var3" {
  type = map(object({
    value              = string
   secret             = bool
   secret_id          = optional(string)
   identity_client_id = optional(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "my-named-value-1" = {
     value              = ""
     secret             = true
     secret_id          = "https://keyvault3.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret1003"
   }
 "my-named-value-2" = {
     value              = ""
      secret             = true
      secret_id          = "https://keyvault4.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret1003"
   }
  }
 }

To extract the key vault id from this variable i'm using the below code
 locals {
   key_vault_names = distinct(
    compact(
      concat(
        [
          var.var1!= null ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,24})", var.var1.key_vault_id) : null,
          var.var2!= null ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,24})", var.var2.key_vault_id) : null
        ],
        [
          for value in values(var.var3) : regex("https://([^.]+).vault.azure.net", value.secret_id) if value.secret_id != ""
       ]
     )
   )
  )
}

 data "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vaults" {
  for_each = toset(local.key_vault_names)
  name     = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
 }

locals {
  key_vault_ids = [
    for kv in data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vaults : kv.id
   ]
 }

But it is failing because of below code
Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│
│   26:     compact(
│   27:       concat(
 │   28:         [
│   29:            var.var1!= null ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,24})", 
var.var1.key_vault_id) : null,
         var.var2!= null ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,24})", var.var2.key_vault_id) 
  : null
  │   32:         ],
  │   33:         # [
  │   34:         #   for value in values(var.var3) : 
 regex("https://([^.]+).vault.azure.net", value.secret_id) if value.secret_id != ""
 │   35:         # ]
 │   36:       )
 │   37:     )
 │     ├────────────────
 │     │ while calling compact(list)
 │     │ var.var2 is a object
 │     │ var.var2.key_vault_id is a string
 │     │ var.var1 is a object
 │     │ var.var1.key_vault_id is a string
 │     │ var.var3 is map of object with 2 elements

 │ 
 │ Invalid value for "list" parameter: element 0: string required.
 ╵
   Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)


The error might be because the regex function returns a list, but you're trying to use it in a context that expects a string @mystack

Could you please rename your variables to something meaningful? var1, var2 and var3 are terrible names that can lead to confusion.


Fetching Azure keyvault id from two types of Terraform variable inputs

As per the document the regex function returns a list but you're referring it to place where it requires string.
Retry changing your locals as mentioned below so that you fetch the key vault ids as required.
Configuration:
variable "var1" {
  type = object({
    host_name    = string
    key_vault_id = optional(string)
  })
  default = {
    host_name    = "api.example.com"
    key_vault_id = "https://tesagsbvk.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret1"
  }
}

variable "var2" {
  type = object({
    host_name    = string
    key_vault_id = optional(string)
  })
  default = {
    host_name    = "portal.example.com"
    key_vault_id = "https://tesagsbvk2.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret2"
  }
}

variable "var3" {
  type = map(object({
    host_name    = string
    key_vault_id = optional(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "tesagsbvk5" = {
      host_name    = "app.example.com"
      key_vault_id = "https://tesagsbvk5.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret5"
    }
    "tesagsbvk6" = {
      host_name    = "service.example.com"
      key_vault_id = "https://tesagsbvk6.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret6"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  key_vault_names = compact(concat(
    [
      length(regexall("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", var.var1.key_vault_id)) > 0 ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", var.var1.key_vault_id)[0] : "",
      length(regexall("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", var.var2.key_vault_id)) > 0 ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", var.var2.key_vault_id)[0] : "",
    ],
    [for value in var.var3 : (
      length(regexall("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", value.key_vault_id)) > 0 ? regex("https://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).vault.azure.net/secrets/.*", value.key_vault_id)[0] : ""
    )]
  ))
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vaults" {
  for_each = toset(local.key_vault_names)
  name     = each.key
  resource_group_name = "vinay-rg"  
}

output "key_vault_ids" {
  value = {
    for name, key_vault in data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vaults : name => key_vault.id
  }
}

Deployment:

Refer:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/assert/latest/docs/functions/regex
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/waf_regex_match_set.html

It Worked .  Thank you @Vinay

Glad to know it works for you @mystack
